# Node - Test if string contain element of array replace him by random element of same array (synonym)

Tags: node.js, arrays, replace

### I want to change each word that matches the synonym list randomly by another synonym or itself (to randomly keep this keyword).

I test if a string (input) contains one element of an array (words). If it's true, I want to randomly replace this with the element of this same list.

```
var input = "This is an amazing text blob where this word amazing is replaced by a random word from list_of_words. Isn't this amazing!";
words_synonym = ["amazing", "formidable", "great", "smart"];

// first condition --> true if "input" contain one element of "words_synonym"
input = input.toLowerCase();
console.log(words_synonym.some(word => input.includes(word)));
```

after, I want to replace the "element" that validated the condition with a random element of the same array (words_synonym).
**But I can't select this element. I have just true or false**

```
var random_word = words_synonym[Math.floor(Math.random() * (words_synonym.length))]
input = input.replace(element, random_word, 0)
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

The way you have it right now, you're checking if any of the synonyms match any of the words (via `words_synonym.some(word => input.includes(word))`). In order to do what you want, you'll need both the position of the target word and the new word, neither of which you have now. To do this, you'll want to break apart your nested loops.

The code `words_synonym.some(word => input.includes(word))` is equivalent to:

```
let has_synonym = false;
for (word of words_synonym) { // this is a loop
    if (input.includes(word)) { // this is also a loop
        has_synonym = true;
        break;
    }
}
console.log(has_synonym);
```

So to fix your main issue, just replace `includes` with `indexOf`.

To handle the case of replacing all of the tokens, I would suggest keeping track of the token you have replaced outside of the loop, otherwise you end up replacing each token many times which may become very expensive. To do this, just keep track of your starting position outside of the loop and increment it with the end index of the replacement word. `indexOf` already takes a `start` argument for exactly this use case!

```js
const input = "This is an amazing text blob where this word amazing is replaced by a random word from list_of_words. Isn't this amazing!";
const words_synonym = ["amazing", "formidable", "great", "smart"];

let output = input;
let start = 0; // index of the end of the last replaced token
for (word of words_synonym) {
    let index = output.indexOf(word, start);
    while (index >= 0) {
        const new_word = words_synonym[Math.floor(Math.random() * (words_synonym.length))];
        output = output.substr(0, index) + new_word + output.substr(index + word.length, output.length);
        start = index + new_word.length + 1; // increment the start
        index = output.indexOf(word, start);
    }
}
console.log("input: ", input);
console.log("output: ", output);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. how to treat ALL the synonyms of the sentence "input" rather than only the first one?

Comment: @gandolfi I have updated my answer to address your additional concern. A key note is that your solution reconsiders every position for each synonym.

Answer (score 0):

You can use method `find`:

```
words_synonym.find(word => input.includes(word))
```

Which returns

> The value of the first element in the array that satisfies the
> provided testing function. Otherwise, undefined is returned.

from docs:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Answer (score 0):

i have modify answer of dantiston and i have include a loop in order to change all the word match "words_synonym".

**But there is a problem. The program don't check all the word of "words_synonym" but only the first with indexof.**

```
var input = "This is an amazing text blob where this word amazing is replaced by a random word from list_of_words. Isn't this amazing!";
words_synonym = ["amazing", "formidable", "great", "smart"];
let output = input;
for (word of words_synonym) {

    let index = output.indexOf(word);
    if (index >= 0) {

        console.log(word);
        var indexes = [], i = -1;
        while ((i = output.indexOf(word, i+1)) != -1){
            index=output.indexOf(word, i);
   
        var new_word = words_synonym[Math.floor(Math.random() * (words_synonym.length))];

        output = output.substr(0, index) + new_word + output.substr(index + word.length, output.length);
        }
    }
}
console.log("input:  ", input);
console.log("output: ", output);
```